# How can I export a list of values in a single field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to join table A and B with B.c being a column that returns multiple strings as list. When I do an inner join with

```
select A.x, B.c
from A
join B
on A.y=B.y
```

I get an output with [number of values in list] rows per observation. Is there a way to write the list into a single field in the result table so I get a single row per observation?

UPDATE:

```
select profiles.name, profiles.street_no, profiles.street_name, profiles.postal_code, profiles.city, profiles.country_code, profiles.owner, profiles_emails.email, profiles_telephones.telephone, clusters.main_topic, group_concat(profiles_tags.tag)
from profiles
    join profiles_emails
        on profiles.id=profiles_emails.profiles_id 
    join profiles_telephones
        on profiles.id=profiles_telephones.profiles_id
    join profiles_tags
        on profiles.id=profiles_tags.profiles_id
    join profiles_clusters
        on profiles_clusters.profiles_id=profiles.id
            join clusters
                on profiles_clusters.clusters_id=clusters.id
group by profiles.city, profiles.name, profiles.street_no, profiles.street_name, profiles.postal_code, profiles.country_code, profiles.owner, profiles_emails.email, profiles_telephones.telephone, clusters.main_topic
```

The group by of course takes way too much time and the desired output is simply a table with all the selected columns and the last column as list.

Comment: Post some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you need  group_concat ..
assuming you have several b.c values for each a.x value you could use a group_concat eg:

```
  select A.x, group_concat(B.c)
  from A
  join B  on A.y=B.y
  group by a.x
```

Comment: thanks, that helps. although I don't really understand why I need to group by every column I specify in the select, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: if you update you question and add the code you are using i can eval you real problem ..  and better   you should add a real data sample and the expected  result  ..    anyway of you are using mysql 5.7  you must add in group by all the column that are not in aggregation function  (this is the correct way for group by)  ..

Comment: Ok, did so. I think we are on the right track, now the query obviously takes forever with this many columns in the group by...

Comment: the cost for group by is not related  to the column  .. (eventually is related  to the cardinality of the rows involved.. ) but for me if the query is slow this could be related  to the join  .. then be sure you  have proper index on all column involved  in join  .. expecially for the bigger tables ...anyway  .. is my answer  right ?

Comment: before  what ? ... ..before group  by .. without  .. aggregation function (group_concat) ?? .. how many rows  you have in each tables .?. and have checked if the proper index  are present ?  ..

Comment: then  tell me numbers of rows in all the tables  and the index for all joins?

Comment: numbers of rows are about 200k per table. what do you mean by index for all joins? how can I find out?

Comment: i mean that you should have index  for  profiles_emails.profiles_id,  ... profiles_telephones.profiles_id, ...  profiles_tags.profiles_id .... profiles_clusters.profiles_id  ... profiles_clusters.clusters_id  .. or at least on the most populated ..